# Why did South Texas shift towards the Republicans?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, identity-politics, texas

The results of the 2020 US election are coming into focus, and, broadly speaking, there remains a large gap between how racial/linguistic groups vote. The Republicans ran a [distinctly](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/07/29/us/politics/trump-suburbs-housing-white-voters.html) [racist](https://www.vox.com/2016/7/25/12270880/donald-trump-racist-racism-history) [white-identitarian](https://www.cambridge.org/nl/academic/subjects/politics-international-relations/american-government-politics-and-policy/white-identity-politics?format=HB&isbn=9781108475525) campaign,* and again attracted a lot of support from white working class and rural voters, and retained an overall advantage among white voters. On the other hand, Latinx and, especially, black voters heavily supported Democrats. There were some localized shifts, with, notably, many Latinx voters shifting towards the Republicans in South Florida and South Texas.

The S. Florida shift is fairly easy to account for, as the largely Cuban-American Latinx community there is skeptical of left-wing politics due to concerns about left-wing regimes in Latin America. Also, reporting before the election flagged a large amount of misinformation about Joe Biden and the Democrats as circulating in S. Florida for whatever reason ([‘This is f---ing crazy’: Florida Latinos swamped by wild conspiracy theories //A flood of disinformation and deceptive claims is damaging Joe Biden in the nation’s biggest swing state.](https://www.politico.com/news/2020/09/14/florida-latinos-disinformation-413923)).

The S. Texas shift is more surprising, at least to me, and doesn't particularly seem to have carried over to other largely Mexican-American areas of Arizona or California. So what accounts for this shift?

<sub>*Response to some comments about this language: That the Republican Party under Trump has run racist campaigns is the mainstream judgement of the field of political science and of reputable media outlets, as those added links may indicate. The point of mentioning this is not to "soapbox" but to indicate a reason that a shift towards the GOP within a minority group is at least somewhat surprising or interesting.</sub>

Comment: Downvoters who explain their reasoning can be helpful to those of us who are wondering what might be wrong with this question.  Have I overlooked something?

Comment: The stated reason for the close vote was "It does not appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more about governments, policies and political processes," Well, it is def. a good-faith question. I don't think it is unhelpful for me to mention my reasoning behind the question, or reference pretty academically uncontroversial assessments of the racial/linguistic disparities in voting and of S. Florida.

Comment: I am providing two conjectures, so not an answer. (1) The ancestors of many of the Hispanics in Texas were in Texas before Texas was Texas. They do not see themselves as immigrants. OTOH, illegal immigration has severe negative impacts on those near the border. (2) To many conservative Catholics, the words "legal" and "abortion" are two words that do not belong on the same page, let alone side by side.. Hispanics in Texas are much more religious than are Americans as a whole, their religion is largely Catholicism, and it tends to be a rather conservative branch of Catholicism.

Comment: 'The Republicans ran a distinctly racist white-identitarian campaign' this is almost certainly the source of the downvoted and bad-faith close votes. I recommend moderating the language.

Comment: @Jontia I think the author meant to refer to *white identity politics* as coined by a professor at Duke University. I think [this article in The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/ideas/archive/2019/08/who-does-trumps-white-identity-politics-reach/595189/) gives some more context on the term.

Comment: @JJJ I'm not sure who coined the term, but that is the kind of thing I was referencing.

Comment: @Colin yea I'm not sure if the added *"distinctly racist"* is really helpful here. The question itself is interesting, but with the added value judgement it might seem as though you're trying to make a political point. That's not what this site if for, and the community may choose to close it as a [bad faith effort](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3040).

Comment: The fact that the GOP ran a racist campaign (etc) is more or less integral to the question because it's what makes it somewhat contrary to expectation that there would be a shift to supporting them within a group targeted by that racism. I don't think the term white identitarian alone really captures it.

Comment: @Colin alright, that's up to you. Though I must say that I don't find it really convincing. It might help if you have a reference that LatinX Texans who have been in Texas since before Texas was Texas (as David put it) were the target of a racist campaign by the GOP.

Comment: @JJJ BTW I don't think it's true that a majority or near majority of Hispanic S. Texans have roots in Texas going back quite as far as that. The Wiki article for Hispanos vaguely suggests a population of Hispanos in Texas in the 100s of thousands, whereas the number of Hispanic Texans is well above 10 million.

Comment: The question comes across as an attempt to soapbox your opinions about the "distinctly racist" nature of a political party you dislike, rather than anything intended in an honest spirit of understanding. It doesn't help that your supporting/explanatory link for that part is to someone offering to sell me a book for 75 pounds sterling. Writing phrases like "Cuban-American Latinx community" doesn't help either. Try asking the people you're referring to whether they like being referred to as such. By the surveys I've seen, the answer is very much no.

Comment: "your supporting/explanatory link for that part is to someone offering to sell me a book for 75 pounds sterling" wasn't actually added by me. "Writing phrases like "Cuban-American Latinx community" doesn't help either." Latinx is one term among several imperfect options and this issue is irrelevant to the substance of the question.

Comment: It's really hard to read this in any good faith light. It asserts that Republicans ran a racist (and *deliberately* racist) campaign and then links to a highly partisan book as proof. Worse, the link is worthless (it's a link to buy the book, where presumably you can read these salacious details) and so demanding the mention remain leaves us with the question "Why would South Texas Latinx people vote for a Republican party that hates them?" What's sad is the base question (without the assertion S.Texas Republicans are blatantly racist) isn't a bad one.

Comment: @Machavity "Distinctly racist" means racist to a noticeable degree, not necessarily intentionally. The link to the book was edited in by someone else, I guess as an explanation for the term "white identitarian". I'm not sure what basis you have for describing the book as "highly partisan", however. Its author is a professor of PoliSci at Duke University, and the book itself apparently won the 2020 American Political Science Association award for "best book in political psychology."

Comment: @TylerH Austin, San Antonio, and Houston are not in South Texas -- more like 150-250 miles from it.

Comment: @shoover They're in the southern half of Texas, but whatever you say.

Comment: @TylerH "South Texas" is the name of a region of Texas, not just a general southern part of Texas. Nobody but Wikipedia thinks San Antonio is in South Texas. Texans generally consider SATx to be between South Texas and Central Texas / Hill Country. No one at all considers Austin and Houston to be South Texas.  Austin is Central Texas / Hill Country. Houston is Gulf Coast. Regions as used by Texas Comptroller's office: https://comptroller.texas.gov/economy/economic-data/regions/2020/index.php

Comment: Lyon is in the southern half of France, but Lyon is not in the South of France.

Comment: The footnote included cites no sources to assert the claims made. A claim from the entire field of political science is a bold statement and will require citation. The article linked under racism is from a highly partisan site.  Further, making a distinction between Latinx Cuban-Americans and non-Latinx Cuban-Americans, by your admission is irrelevant to the question, begs to ask why you would do it if it wasn't for the soapbox.

Answer (score 6):

Insofar I haven't seen much beyond expert opinion on this, and most of it focused on Trump's [win in Florida](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/latino/trump-cultivated-latino-vote-florida-it-paid-n1246226), where the Trump campaign advertised heavily in Spanish describing Biden as a (Venezuela-like) socialist, but for what that's worth, [this](https://www.vox.com/21551025/latino-national-vote-biden-trump-2020-florida-texas) was suggested about south Texas:

> In South Texas, for example, Trump’s “law and order” messaging and opposition to defunding the police had some resonance in Latino communities where law enforcement, particularly the Border Patrol, is a major employer, Garcia [president of the League of United Latin American Citizens (LULAC)] said. Many residents also work in oil fields and fear Democrats’ calls to transition away from oil and gas and towards clean, renewable energy. And many are Catholic or Evangelical Christians who find Democrats’ pro-abortion rights stance abhorrent.

The Politico article from ohwilleke's answer eventually cites some experts along the same lines:

> Trump’s success in the Rio Grande Valley, says Daniel Arreola, a cultural geographer and author of* Tejano South Texas*, “peels back the onion on how really conservative that Tejano ranch and small-town rural population is.”
>
> From the brush of Laredo across more than 200 miles to the lush delta of Brownsville, there’s a legacy of a frontier culture that lives on. A place like Zapata is oil country. On weekends, the town empties out as people head into the ranchland to hunt, and nearly everyone is proudly gun-toting and God-fearing. In the deeply Catholic county, support for abortion is practically nonexistent, while support for law enforcement, the military and even Border Patrol is rock-solid.

In a parallel with what [DW noted](https://www.dw.com/en/a-florida-latina-wants-to-give-donald-trump-4-more-years/a-55378721) about Cuban Americans in Florida, Tejanos interviewed by Politico didn't feel targeted by Trump's negative rhetoric:

> While many Trump supporters in South Texas, like Trappe, have Mexican roots and say they can understand how the president’s crude and derogatory language might seem divisive to some, few of them hear the president talking about them when he makes comments about Mexicans.
>
> “I think when people say they don’t like Mexicans, to me it means a Mexican citizen, or a Mexican national, who has crossed illegally,” says Barrera, the Starr County Republicans chair. “And then again, not all Mexicans look alike. So when they say they don’t like Mexicans, I don’t think it means me. … It means a Mexican national who has broken the law.”

Answer (score 5):

Politico conducted an in depth analysis of this question entitled "[Trump Didn't Win The Latino Vote in Texas. He Won The Tejano Vote](https://www.politico.com/news/magazine/2020/11/17/trump-latinos-south-texas-tejanos-437027?fbclid=IwAR0bqKlY_0V1KGeWsmghYoUrtDcY728eRoa5cDuy8I5yKLgwBNyDDuC9TOE)." According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tejanos):

> Tejanos (Spanish: [teˈhano]; singular: Tejano/a/x; Spanish for
> "Texan") are the Hispanic residents of the state of Texas who are
> culturally descended from the original Spanish-speaking settlers of
> Tejas, Coahuila, and other northern Mexican states. They may be
> variously of Criollo Spaniard or Mestizo origin.

The gist of the analysis is that this specific community of Spanish speaking people who mostly see themselves as Mexican-Texan rather than as Hispanic or Latino, are not immigrants, mostly self-identify as "white" in race, and have a lot of broad agreement with Republican views.

The analysis is less clear about why their votes shifted so much from 2016 to 2020, but an active grassroots campaign carefully targeted to this particular community no doubt played a part.

Comment: "The analysis is less clear about why their votes shifted so much from 2016 to 2020" --yeah I guess this answer is on the right track, but the voting pattern of South Texas Tejanos has been very different than non-Hispanic white Texans historically.